# Cant access the json data

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to access json data.

```
console.log(result);
console.log(result.data);
console.log(result['data']);
```

console shows.

```
{"code":200,"success":true,"data":"songlist"} 
undefined 
undefined
```

How come can't I access the internal data of json.....

Comment: You're sure it's not a string, try `console.log( typeof result )`

Comment: It works fine http://jsbin.com/IradElOJ/1/edit. Problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I'm going with the "string theory". Hahahaha. You're welcome.

Comment: If `console.log(result);` results in `{"code":200,"success":true,"data":"songlist"}`, then `result` is a string.

Comment: How are you producing and getting that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse it into a js object

```
console.log(result);
result = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(result);
console.log(result.data);
console.log(result['data']);
```

Comment: Thanks it slove my problem perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You may also use eval; although it poses serious security issue

```
eval( 'var oResult = ' + result );
console.log( oResult.data );
```

Comment: Why would you ever use `eval` if you can use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: IE, remember? JSON is not supported until IE 9 I suppose.

Comment: eval is great, there's just no other function that is as useful as eval, it's just a shame you should (almost) **never ever ever** use it.

Comment: Even then you should rather use https://github.com/bestiejs/json3.